# JavaScript Form Validation Not Showing Alert or Changing Input Background Colour

Tags: javascript, html

I made this script to validate my forms however, when I leave a textfield blank nothing happens, there is no red background to the input box or alert message as I expected there to be.

```
function validateForm()
{
/* For all forms in the document */
for(var i in document.forms)
{
    /* Get the forms inputs */
    var inputs = document.forms[i].getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var j in inputs)
    {
        /* Make sure we don't try to validate the submit button */
        if(inputs[j].type == "text")
        {
            if(inputs[j].value.trim() == "" || inputs[j].value.trim() == null)
            {
                inputs[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                alert("Please ensure all boxes are filled in");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is one of my forms if that helps:

```
<form name="searchArtists" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="artists" placeholder="Search Artists" maxlength="255" size="32" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Err, I'm no JS expert, but shouldn't that be "if( inputs[j].value == ""  or similar?  Otherwise, what connects the "value" with one of the inputs?

Comment: @MartynA Yeh I wrote "value" as another variable that I ended up not using but didn't update that part of the code, I updated it now as you suggested but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your default value is 'Search artists', check for it, too, and/or clear default value on click.... https://jsfiddle.net/jbrhodpz/ When you remove it from text field, it works as expected...

Comment: @nevermind I don't want to do that because I don't think I could do it without having to change the script for each form which is what I tried to avoid in the first place. Secondly if they want to search for "Search Artists" then that's fine, the PHP behind the query will just print "No artists were found". As I post this, you edited lol. I will change it to remove on click. I was testing it by removing the text manually and it wasn't working although as you say it works in the fiddle, strange.

Answer (score 2):

Use placeholder attribute for placeholder text

```
<input type="text" name="artists" placeholder="Search Artists"...
```

Another issue I suggest to don't allow spaces as well

```
if(inputs[j].value.trim() == "") { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added them in. I'm still confused as to why it works in a jsfiddle but not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `i` is a form and `j` is an input. Because of that, `document.forms[i]` and `inputs[j]` don't work.

Fixed JavaScript function:

```
function validateForm()
{
    /* For all forms in the document */
    for(var i in document.forms)
    {
        /* Get the forms inputs */
        var inputs = i.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for(var j in inputs)
        {
            /* Make sure we don't try to validate the submit button */
            /* Trim value to not allow values with only spaces */
            if(j.type == "text")
            {
                if(j.value == null || j.value.trim() == "")
                {
                    j.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    alert("Please ensure all boxes are filled in");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="searchArtists" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="artists" placeholder="Search Artists" maxlength="255" size="32" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's cut this down a bit, first add an ID to the element we want to validate, I also suggest changing your current "value" to a "placeholder", like so:

```
<input id="artistQueryInput" type="text" name="artists" placeholder="Search Artists" maxlength="255" size="32" />
```

Now on to the Javascript:

```
function validateForm(){
    //Get element
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('artistQueryInput');

    //Get value
    var rawArtistQueryString = inputElement.value;

    //Strip all whitespace
    var baseArtistQueryString = rawArtistQueryString.replace(/ /g, "");

    //Validate string without whitespace
    if((baseArtistQueryString == '') || (baseArtistQueryString == NULL) ||){
         //Assuming j is artistQueryInput
         inputElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
         alert("Please ensure all boxes are filled in");
         return false;
    }
}
```